# Pandas date conversion assuming wrong date format

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to convert a pandas date column to YYYY-MM-DD and then restrict the date based of a parameter min_date.

The problem is when trying to covert dd/mm/yyyy from the df to the required format, pandas assumes the date is us style, i.e. 06/07/2020 is converted to 2020-06-07

I scoured stackoverflow but cannot find someone with a similar issue, the usual answers are just to use strftime, but this does not work for my use case.

Snippet of code:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

#date restriction
min_date = datetime.strptime(str("2020-06-01"),"%Y-%m-%d").date()

#convert html from website to DF
df = pd.read_html("https://webgate.ec.europa.eu/rasff-window/portal/index.cfm?event=notificationsList")[0]

#only use certain columns
df = df[["Subject","Date of case"]]
df.rename(columns={"Subject": "Description", "Date of case": "Date" }, inplace=True)

#adding another date column to easily compare the old vs new date
df["Date1"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"]).dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
df = df[df["Date1"] > min_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')]

print(df[["Date","Date1","Description"]])
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need compare datetimes, not strings repr of datetimes, also is added `dayfirst=True` parameter in [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) and changed format to `DD/MM/YYYY` in [`Series.dt.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html):

```
#date restriction
min_date = datetime.strptime(str("2020-06-01"),"%Y-%m-%d")

#convert html from website to DF
u = "https://webgate.ec.europa.eu/rasff-window/portal/index.cfm?event=notificationsList"
df = pd.read_html(u)[0]

#only use certain columns
df = df[["Subject","Date of case"]]
df.rename(columns={"Subject": "Description", "Date of case": "Date" }, inplace=True)

#adding another date column to easily compare the old vs new date

#converted to datetimes
df["Date1"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"], dayfirst=True)
#compare
df = df[df["Date1"] > min_date].copy()
#or compare by string
#df = df[df["Date1"] > "2020-06-01"].copy()
#change to custom format
df["Date1"] = df["Date1"].dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
```

---

```
print(df[["Date","Date1","Description"]])
          Date       Date1                                        Description
0   06/07/2020  06/07/2020  presence of lactose (>1 250 mg/kg - ppm) in la...
1   06/07/2020  06/07/2020  high content of vitamin B9 - folic acid (1388 ...
2   06/07/2020  06/07/2020  high content of vitamin B9 - folic acid (1189 ...
3   06/07/2020  06/07/2020  aflatoxins (B1 = 25.4 µg/kg - ppb) in groundnu...
4   06/07/2020  06/07/2020  poor temperature control (-10.2 °C) of frozen ...
..         ...         ...                                                ...
95  24/06/2020  24/06/2020  unauthorised genetically modified micro-organi...
96  24/06/2020  24/06/2020  Salmonella (in 2 out of 5 samples /25g) in pro...
97  24/06/2020  24/06/2020  horse which has not undergone sufficient withd...
98  24/06/2020  24/06/2020  unauthorised genetically modified (positive fo...
99  24/06/2020  24/06/2020    2,4-dinitrophenol (DNP) offered online for sale

[100 rows x 3 columns]
```

Comment: @TobiasFunke - Sorry, now I get same output.